# How to edit the Bootstrap mobile collapsed dropdown menu layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to go about creating a custom dropdown menu for bootstrap when the page is in mobile mode (or any mode really that would display the hamburger button). I know how to manipulate the button itself but google search after google search I cannot find any good articles or posts about creating a custom bootstrap dropdown.

I am currently using the "out of the box" ul/li listed menu that Bootstrap uses by default but cannot figure out how to manipulate it so that when "mobile mode" is in use it switches to this style.

This is how my nav looks now:

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#home"><img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-center">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">

                <li>
                    <a href="/link/">Link</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/link/">Link</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/link/">Link</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/link/">
                        <div class="btn btn-outline btn-sm">Sign Up</div>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/link/">
                        <div class="btn btn-outline btn-sm">Sign In</div>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

[image: bootstrap nav]

I made this quick concept of what I am trying to do but I cannot figure out where to start to where it won't affect my current nav which is just links/buttons aligned to the right.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is the "standard" one different from what you want? A jsfiddle/codepen of the problem would help us helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult at all. Its all just CSS: create a div inside a list item and place two buttons there. Float them so there to the right of the rest of your links since they'll be the first li item, style them however.

Then adjust them for mobile by removing the float and add whatever styles you want.

See example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom .signin {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ccc;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom a.btn.navbar-btn.btn-sign {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:not(:first-child) {
    right: 90px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom a.btn.navbar-btn.btn-sign {
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .signin {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" class="img-responsive">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="signin"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-sign">Sign Up</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-sign">Sign in</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/link/">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/link/">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/link/">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/link/">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Man, I hate how obvious that was, but also love it. THANK YOU. This is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: No problem and just keep in mind if you never try, you'll never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here how i usually do this.
Create a separate CSS file and added to you html.
Detect the screen size.
Write CSS to overwrite the Boostrap css once you hit the screen size that you consider as mobile.
Look at this post that has extended example on CSS for mobile divices.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/